# PDO: difference between rowCount() and SQL COUNT(col)

Tags: mysql, count, pdo

I just wonder to know if is better to use PDO class `rowCount` method instead of SQL `COUNT(col_name)` to count the number of rows.

Does exist some recommended situation for each one?

Comment: COUNT(col_name) returns the number of columns of certain condition found for a select query. affected rows usually refers to update, delete, insert statements. COUNT is a SQL function but rowCount is a driver feature returning number of rows returned with a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference?  This disclaimer on [the `rowCount` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, *some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement*. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases** and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Emphasis added.

If you need the number of records in the database that match, use `COUNT()`.  If you need the number of rows that the database driver believes it's returning to you / the number of affected rows in the database drivers that support that concept, then use PDO's `rowCount`, but you can't guarantee that data will be there, depending on the underlying database driver.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rowCount because it's implemented in the driver. COUNT() requires mysql do additional work which may or may not be a problem in your instance.