# For SQL row count, is it more efficient to use PDO rowCount or count(*) AS?

Tags: php, mysql

On my script, I have about 15 SQL queries just for counting the number of rows and displaying them to the user.

What is the most efficient way?

Should I use:

```
$stmt=$cxn->prepare("SELECT id FROM items WHERE seller=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Or this:

```
$stmt=$cxn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as count FROM items WHERE seller=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));   
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    echo $row['count'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315550/pdo-difference-between-rowcount-and-sql-countcol

Comment: One more thing, you can group the 15 select count(*)s in to one statement, that might be faster.

Comment: Yes sounds good. It would look better too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Count(*) will be faster.

However, that assumes your not using the data, if you are going to select the data, and you want a count, then use your first method.

```
("SELECT id FROM items WHERE seller=?");
```

If you have an index on the table, then that will return almost instantly.

Comment: Not using the COUNT aggregate means the database will return all the rows, send those over the wire to PHP, which will then report the count.  Extremely inefficient use of bandwidth...

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I see you point, Count seems more viable. Regards

Comment: Yea.. What I mean is, use count, but not if your going to also fetch the data.  If you want the data and the count, do the select and then use ->rowCount().   If your not using the data, just use count(1) in the select.

Answer (score 1):

The rowCount command can be used not only for SELECT queries but also for UPDATE,INSERT etc.
So that's a benefit for that.

However according to the PDO documentation :

> not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

So in your case i'd suggest using count without worrying about preformence, though it will slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster to use the MySQL row count. Less bandwidth is needed between PHP and the database.

Comment: Neither rowCount() or $row['count'] communicate with the server. It simply fetches the data from the result set, which is already in memory in PHP. `SELECT id` returns a much larger result set, which uses a lot more bandwidth, than `SELECT COUNT(*)`, which only returns a single integer value in a single row.